# Folder structure in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a problem with folder structure of MVC2

How can I use that way:

```
Folder:
├── Controllers
│   └── Portal
│       ├── Accounting
│       │   ├── CashController.cs
│       │   └── BankController.cs
│       └── HR
│           └──  EmployeesController.cs Models
└── Views
    └── Portal
        └── Accounting
            ├── Cash
            │   ├── Index.aspx
            │   └── List.aspx
            ├── Bank
            │   └── Index.aspx
            └── HR
                ├── Index.aspx
                └── Employee.aspx
```

How can I use folder structure like that and how can I route the URL with the right form.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You might want to consider using Areas and dropping the Portal folder since it's just a wrapper.

So you will end up with something like this :

```
Areas
├── Accounting
│   ├── Controllers
│   │   ├── CashController.cs
│   │   └── BankController.cs
│   └── Views
│       ├── Cash
│       │   ├── Index.aspx
│       │   └── List.aspx
│       └── Bank
│           └── Index.aspx
└── HR
    ├── Controllers
    │   └── EmployeesController.cs
    └── Views
        └── Employees
            ├── Index.aspx
            └── Employee.aspx
```

More on Areas [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx)

Or just use any structure you want and change the namesspaces to match the default (not recommended).